# High quality, low-noise, pre-amp circuit for condenser microphone (with phantom power)?

Tags: fet, preamp, condenser-microphone

EDIT

---

Suggestions so far, and reference to another question indicate that a discrete FET based input stage, perhaps followed by a particular low-noise IC for a second stage, might be a good approach.

I have zero experience with FETs in analog situations, so any pointers (actual circuits make great pointers :) on that would be hugely appreciated.

Also, I'm still have no clue how to generate 48 Volts from what will probably be a 9 v battery, nor the best way to integrate that as phantom power on the input. On the latter part, I'm guessing a simple capacitor coupling would protect the input stage from the power voltage, but I suspect there are "thump" and noise considerations in all that too. Again, any guidance will be most welcome.

---

Mostly for the fun of it (i.e. I don't really care that I can probably buy this pre-made cheaper, but I do want to build something of high quality) I'd like to build a pre-amp for a condenser microphone.

My main criterion for this would be low noise, though the response should be reasonably flat out to 20 kHz (which is the upper band of the condenser mics I would use this with) and minimal distortion (yes, I realize those aren't really quantitative descriptions, but my pre-amp tinkering in the past (perhaps 30 years ago) suggest the latter two weren't the hard part, but the noise was always the bit that bugged me.

Of course, this needs 48 V phantom power, and I need to generate that too (which I've never done before, so that's very definitely a key part of this question).

Can anyone offer suggests for circuits? Or perhaps recommend a resource? Perhaps a book, website, whatever?

Comment: Google for INA217 mic preamp, they can be built cheaply and offer good performance. The Ti Datasheet has an example circuit, though doesn't show the phantom power generation.

Comment: Some discussion here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215923/low-noise-amplification-of-microphone-signals-tubes-or-chips