# Maximizing signal to noise ratio for very small radiation detector

Tags: signal, signal-to-noise, detector

I have a very small radiation detector that outputs signal of small amplitude. Requires preamplification before going to an actual amplifier. When constructing the system prior to the preamp, would I like to have higher resistance or lower resistance? I know ohms law, and smaller wires have higher resistance thus greater induced voltage from the sensor. The key factor for me is signal to noise ratio.

So in summary small vs. large wires and any other recommendations to keep in mind?

Comment: Welcome Jake.  Please post a schematic so that we may be better able to help you.  Also, indicate which wires you are referring to.

Comment: Jake, if the key factor is S/N then we need to know a great deal about the bandwidth you actually require. There is a lot that can be done if you can limit that right at the sensor-to-preamp interface. The detector type would also help a great deal. "Detector" doesn't say much -- only that it is a transducer (everything in the universe is a transducer in some fashion) and that it can produce some kind of electric signalling. Keeping things to yourself is the last thing you want to do, right now. Put everything up onto the table for us to see.

Comment: Knowing the source impedance of the sensor is critical here. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215923/low-noise-amplification-of-microphone-signals-tubes-or-chips for some discussion.